# Truncate a table in GBQ

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to truncate an existing table in GBQ but the below command fails when I run it. Is there any specific command or syntax to do that. I looked into GBQ documentation but no luck.

```
TRUNCATE TABLE [dw_test.test];
```

Comment: Please have look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44651237/how-to-delete-truncate-the-data-in-the-table-using-command-line-in-big-query

Comment: As of october 2020, truncate table is supported in bigquery. Please check @Iaol answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**EDIT (Nov 2020): BigQuery now supports other verbs, check other answers for newer solutions.**

BigQuery doesn't support `TRUNCATE` as part of a query string.  The only DDL/DML verb that BQ supports is `SELECT`.

One option is to run a job with `WRITE_TRUNCATE` [write disposition](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#configuration.query.writeDisposition) (link is for the query job parameter, but it's supported on all job types with a destination table).  This will truncate all data already in the table and replace it with the results of the job.

If you don't want to replace the contents with other data or start a job, your best option is probably to delete and recreate the table with the same schema.

Comment: How can I truncate tables from BQ console?

Comment: If you're using the web UI, you can find the `WRITE_TRUNCATE` disposition within the advanced query options.  Under the query editor, click "Show Options" - then set the "Write Preference" option to "Overwrite Table".

Comment: Yeah I have seen that option but just wondering if there are any DDL commands that can do it the way its done in standard SQL dialect.

Comment: Nope, BigQuery only supports `SELECT` in terms of DDL/DML.

Comment: Okay.. So there is nothing even for DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE <> ?

Comment: Correct, there's no support for `DELETE` or `UPDATE` via the query language.  [BigQuery tables are append-only](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#deletingrows), so if you want to update or delete specific rows, you need to recreate the table with just the rows you want to be present.  This could be done with a SELECT * FROM table WHERE NOT(<foo>) with a destination table, however.

Comment: Please update the answer since Bigquery now supports Truncate table as @Iaol mentioned

Comment: @elvainch Edited to suggest checking out other answers.

Answer (score 44):

While BigQuery didn't used to support anything other than `SELECT`s, it now does as long as you uncheck "Use Legacy SQL" in the query options.  There is no truncation, but [you can delete](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#delete_statement):

```
DELETE from my_table WHERE 1=1
```

Note that BigQuery requires the use of `WHERE` in the `DELETE`, so if you want to delete everything you need to use a statement that will always be true.

Comment: `Error: 1.1 - 1.58: Unrecognized token DELETE.` This is the error I am getting when I try this.

Comment: @hrzafer Did you disable Legacy SQL mode in the query options?

Comment: If a table was created with `Require partition filter` flag (for an example by a timestamp column `ts`) then you’ll just need to specify a time window wide enough to delete all data like `DELETE FROM ‘project.dataset.table_name’ WHERE ts BETWEEN TIMESTAMP("1970-01-01") AND TIMESTAMP("2100-01-01")` otherwise you’ll get an error saying query cannot succeed without a filter over column 'ts' that can be used for partition elimination. @XiongChiamiov can you please update your answer with this suggestion?

Answer (score 34):

Good news, TRUNCATE TABLE is supported by now: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#truncate_table_statement

```
TRUNCATE TABLE [[project_name.]dataset_name.]table_name
```

Answer (score 16):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE <dataset>.<table>
AS SELECT * FROM <dataset>.<table> LIMIT 0;
```

For partitionned tables, assuming you have a day partition on field "created_on", then execute the following :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE <dataset>.<table> PARTITION BY created_on
AS SELECT * FROM <dataset>.<table> WHERE created_on = CURRENT_DATE() LIMIT 0;
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide an answer. If you could give some explanation as to how the solution works, that would improve the answer tremendously.

Comment: He is basically selecting only 0 records from the table and trying to replace the table if it exists or creates it. By doing this the table is recreated with the same columns and data types but data.

Comment: This works well in google bigquery, as DELETE will often fail with the streaming buffer

Comment: On partitioned tables, even that won't work. DROP TABLE is the only way.