# How to delete/truncate the data in the table using command line in big query?

Tags: google-bigquery

What is the command to execute DMLs like Insert,Update,Delete in Google Big Query?

I tried using bq query "select query"

It is working only for Select statements

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Truncate a table in GBQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30221670/truncate-a-table-in-gbq)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that [BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/) really excels at being a secondary database used for performing fast analytical queries on big data that is static, such as recorded data analysis, logs, and audit history.

If you instead require regular data updates, [it is highly recommended](https://cloud.google.com/storage-options/) to use a separate master database such as the [Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/) to perform fast entity operations and updates. You would then persist your data from your master database to your secondary BigQuery database for further analysis.

---

Therefore, you must tell the bq commandline to use the full [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/) `--use_legacy_sql=false` instead of the original BigQuery default [legacy SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql) to access the [Data Manipulation Language (DML)](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql#bigquery-enable-sql-cli) functionality.

Comment: Hi @Jordan, cool information! Just wondering, is there some sort of automated job transfer to get data from Datastore and send it to BigQuery? Or is it something we should make using some tool such as Dataflow?

Comment: It is easiest to import your Datastore Kinds into BigQuery via [Datastore backups](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data-cloud-datastore) using the [Cloud Console](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data-cloud-datastore#webui). Once imported, you can then perform writes to [update BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries) every time you write to your Datastore to keep them in sync (or via regular Dataflow jobs to sync the diff). If you don't need regular analysis of the data via queries in BigQuery, you can just perform another backup and import.